# PT2399 delay chip feedback issue

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, feedback

I'm facing a strange issue which I can not identify.

The circuit is the basic PT2399-based echo.
My components setup is based on the research of similar circuits:

[image: circuit]

The problem is that I'm not getting any feedback echo effect with this at all, and also I'm not able to hear the delay effect when I'm turning the corresponding pot (connected to the pin 6).

I can hear the delay effect when I remove the connection between the feedback pot and pin 16 (which is supposed to create a feedback loop) while placing the audio probe right after the feedback pot out.

The similar, but the simpler circuit was working for me (unfortunately I don't have it), a difference is in the LPFs with the internal op-amps in the chip and some capacitors.

Am I missing something?

My audio probe is a simple jack with positive/ground wires, connected to the headphones.
By connecting the circuit output to the audio interface, I'm able to hear the desired effects and it seems to be working properly. But I'm still confused about why it is behaving in that way.

Comment: The circuit can not drive a relatively low impedance load like headphones.  It is designed to drive a high impedance load like an amplifier.  Also, your circuit does not quite match the application circuit from the datasheet.

Comment: It appears that my audio probe should be improved to avoid the impedance mismatch.

Comment: @crj11 thanks for the tip. Regarding the application - I'm building my own one, based on similar circuits that are published before. There a ton of basic configurations for this chip, which is chosen for one's taste.